# Scala Type Inference Confusion: Any or Nothing?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, type-inference

Original Version:

```
  trait Animal[F[_], A]
  case class Cat[F[_], I, A](limits: F[I], f: I => A) extends Animal[F,A]

  object  ConfuseMe {
    def confuse[F[_], A](tt: Animal[F, A]) = tt match {
      case Cat(_, f) => f
    }
  }
```

Modified Version:

```
  trait Animal[A]
  case class Cat[I, A](f: I => A) extends Animal[A]

  object  ConfuseMe {
    def confuse[A](tt: Animal[A]) = tt match {
      case Cat(f) => f
    }
  }
```

If F is List, function confuse of original version will be inferred as Any => A type. The modified version will be inferred as Nothing => A type as default. Why not both of them are of type Nothing => A as implied by IntelliJ IDE? I'm totally confused.

Other Interesting Example:

```
  trait Trampoline[+A]
  case class Done[+A](get: A) extends Trampoline[A]
  case class More[+A](force: () => Trampoline[A]) extends Trampoline[A]
  case class Bind[I,+A](force: () => Trampoline[I], f: I => Trampoline[A]) extends Trampoline[A]
```

It seems like once we have constraints(type constructor) 'Trampoline' over type 'I' here, we have something to say about 'I' like type 'I' have property of 'F'(it could be any type-constructor?), so it will inferred as 'Any' by Scala complier(it doesn't further typecheck type-constructor 'F' to gather more information about 'I', so it just give it 'Any' because it is not SMART enough) otherwise it is tagged 'Nothing' just like we have nothing to say. However, I'm not sure about it and still stuck in confusion.

Comment: I think limit serves as something like Type I has property of F, so it should not be an arbitrary type.

Comment: `def confuse[F[_], A](tt: Animal[F, A]): Whatever => A = tt match {
      case Cat(_, f) => f
    }` seems to always typecheck, no matter what you insert for `Whatever`. That's weird.

Comment: This looks like it might be a bug or at least a case of the type system being unsound. The fact that `Any` is inferred in the original version allows `ConfuseMe.confuse(Cat(Seq(42), (x: Int) => x.toString))("la")` to type check and then cause a `ClassCastException` at runtime, which seems ... not great.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because, after some further testing, most of the details turned out to be wrong. So I'll just say here that this looks related to [this bug](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/8563) and leave a full answer to someone with a better grasp of what's going on.